# How to get solution of following equations?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[{X^2 + Y^2 == 5^2, X1 + a*Cos[g1 + g2] + e*Cos[g3 + h] == X, 
  X1 + d*Cos[g1] - c*Cos[g4] - f*Cos[i - g3] == X, 
  Y1 + a*Sin[g1 + g2] + e*Sin[h + g3] == Y, 
  Y1 + d*Sin[g1] + c*Sin[g4] + e*Sin[i - g3] == Y, 
  X2 - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] + (a*f/b)*Cos[g7] == X, 
  X2 - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] + (e*a/b)*Cos[j + g7] + a*Cos[g1 + g2] == X, 
  X2 + (a*f/b)*Cos[g6] - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] == X, 
  X2 + (a*f/b)*Cos[g6] - (c*f/b)*Cos[j + g5] + c*Cos[g4] == X, 
  Y2 - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] - (a*f/b) Sin[g7] == Y, 
  Y2 - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] - (e*a/b)*Sin[g7 + j] + a*Sin[g1 + g2] == Y, 
  Y2 - (a*f/b) Sin[g6] - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] == Y, 
  Y2 - (a*f/b)*Sin[g6] - (c*f/b)*Sin[j + g5] + c*Sin[g4] == Y, 
  X1 + e*Cos[g1 + g3 + h] + (e*a/b)*
     Cos[g1 + g2 + h] + (a*f/b) Cos[g7] == X, 
  X1 + d*Cos[g1] - 
    f*Cos[i - g3] + (c*f/b)*Cos[g4 + i] - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] == X, 
  Y1 + e*Sin[g1 + g3 + h] + (e*a/b)*Sin[g1 + g2 + h] - (a*f/b)*
     Sin[g7] == Y, 
  Y1 + d*Sin[g1] + 
    f*Sin[i - g3] + (c*f/b)*Sin[g4 + i] - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] == 
   Y, (e/Sin[i]) == (f/Sin[h]) == (b/Sin[j]),X1+e*Cos[h+g3]+(e*a/b)*Cos[h+g1+g2]+(c*e/b)*Cos[g5]==X2,Y1+e*Sin[h+g3]+(e*a/b)*Sin[h+g1+g2]+(c*e/b)*Sin[g5]==Y2}, {X1, Y1, X2, Y2, a, b, 
  c, d, e, f, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, h, i, j}]
```

Where X and Y are coordinates of a circle having centre `0,0` and radius `5`. `a,b,c,d,e,f` are lengths,and `g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,h,i,j` are all angles, What should be a correct syntax for this?

Comment: I count `18` equations and `20` variables to solve for? Also, with non-linear equations, do you think there a chance solve will solve these.

Comment: For this type of problem, it is often useful to substitute `{Cos[g]->cg,Sin[g]->sg}` and add an additional equation `cg^2+sg^2==1`

Comment: The last equation will convert to three equations thus 20 equations

Comment: I think that counting the last expression as three equations is an error. Once you have set `e/Sin[i] == f/Sin[h]` and `e/Sin[i] == b/Sin[j]`, no added information is given by `f/Sin[h] ==  b/Sin[j]` as the previous two equations already established that fact.

Comment: @mikado sorry but i don't know how to do that could you provide me syntax for that

Comment: @JackLaVigne i think you are right, i am going to add 1 more equation here.

Comment: You have neither specified values for `X` `Y` nor tried to solve for them.  Are they known?  And this also means that you again have one equation too few.  (The first only involves `X` and `Y`).

Comment: @mikado well the first equation is of a circle i know that for every possible value of X and Y all the lengths i.e. a,b,c,d,e,f are going to be same as well as angle g1,h,i,j will remain same but the value of g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7 will change as value of X and Y changes.

Answer (score 3):

The following is intended to at least demonstrate the approach I would take to solving these equations.  Apologies if the explanation is a little sketchy - it will probably only make sense if you look at the outputs of every stage.

Take the equations provided by the OP.  Split the `xxx==yyy==zzz` into two equalities for simplicity downstream.

```
eqns = {X^2 + Y^2 == 5^2, X1 + a*Cos[g1 + g2] + e*Cos[g3 + h] == X, 
   X1 + d*Cos[g1] - c*Cos[g4] - f*Cos[i - g3] == X, 
   Y1 + a*Sin[g1 + g2] + e*Sin[h + g3] == Y, 
   Y1 + d*Sin[g1] + c*Sin[g4] + e*Sin[i - g3] == Y, 
   X2 - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] + (a*f/b)*Cos[g7] == X, 
   X2 - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] + (e*a/b)*Cos[j + g7] + a*Cos[g1 + g2] == X, 
   X2 + (a*f/b)*Cos[g6] - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] == X, 
   X2 + (a*f/b)*Cos[g6] - (c*f/b)*Cos[j + g5] + c*Cos[g4] == X, 
   Y2 - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] - (a*f/b) Sin[g7] == Y, 
   Y2 - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] - (e*a/b)*Sin[g7 + j] + a*Sin[g1 + g2] == Y, 
   Y2 - (a*f/b) Sin[g6] - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] == Y, 
   Y2 - (a*f/b)*Sin[g6] - (c*f/b)*Sin[j + g5] + c*Sin[g4] == Y, 
   X1 + e*Cos[g1 + g3 + h] + (e*a/b)*
      Cos[g1 + g2 + h] + (a*f/b) Cos[g7] == X, 
   X1 + d*Cos[g1] - 
     f*Cos[i - g3] + (c*f/b)*Cos[g4 + i] - (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] == X, 
   Y1 + e*Sin[g1 + g3 + h] + (e*a/b)*Sin[g1 + g2 + h] - (a*f/b)*
      Sin[g7] == Y, 
   Y1 + d*Sin[g1] + 
     f*Sin[i - g3] + (c*f/b)*Sin[g4 + i] - (c*e/b)*Sin[g5] == 
    Y, (e/Sin[i]) == (f/Sin[h]), (f/Sin[h]) == (b/Sin[j]), 
   X1 + e*Cos[h + g3] + (e*a/b)*Cos[h + g1 + g2] + (c*e/b)*Cos[g5] == 
    X2};
```

The variables we will attempt to solve for

```
vars = {X1, Y1, X2, Y2, a, b, c, d, e, f, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, 
   h, i, j};
```

and the angular variables

```
varangles = {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, h, i, j};
```

It is simplest if we replace all the trig functions with the sine or cosine of these variables to reduce the complexity of the equations.  Add a `Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2==1` constraint so that we can solve for the additional variables.

```
cosvars = {cg1, cg2, cg3, cg4, cg5, cg6, cg7, ch, ci, cj};
sinvars = {sg1, sg2, sg3, sg4, sg5, sg6, sg7, sh, si, sj};
trigconstraints = Thread[cosvars^2 + sinvars^2 == 1];
trigrules = 
  Join[Thread[Cos /@ varangles -> cosvars], 
   Thread[Sin /@ varangles -> sinvars]];
```

Use trig manipulations to rewrite the equations in terms of the chosen sines and cosines

```
trigterms = 
  Cases[eqns, _Cos | _Sin | _Sec | _Csc, ∞] // Union;
trigtermreplacements = 
  TrigExpand /@ trigterms /. trigrules /. Map[#^-1 &, trigrules, {2}];
subs1 = Thread[trigterms -> trigtermreplacements];
polyeqns = Join[eqns /. subs1, trigconstraints];
```

and the variables we try to solve for are

```
polyvars = Union[Complement[vars, varangles], cosvars, sinvars];
```

We seem to be one short of the equations we need to solve this, so invent one

```
extraeqns = {sg1 == 0.3};
```

We are now in a position to solve this.  `Solve` and `Reduce` seem a bits slow on this (I don't know how many roots it will have so I have used `FindRoot` to search for a solution.  The result will depend on the randomly chosen starting point and won't converge every time (keep trying if necessary).  I chose values for `X` and `Y` consistent with the equations:

```
soln = Block[{X = 3, Y = 4}, 
   FindRoot[Evaluate[List @@ And @@ Join[polyeqns, extraeqns]], 
    Evaluate[{polyvars, RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[polyvars]]} // 
      Transpose]]];
```

To see how close we are to solving the equations, substitute the solution back in

```
Block[{X = 3, Y = 4}, polyeqns /. Equal -> Subtract /. soln]
(* {True, -6.21725*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-14, 9.32587*10^-15, 
 3.55271*10^-15, -1.46549*10^-14, -3.9968*10^-15, -8.88178*10^-16, 
 6.66134*10^-15, -5.32907*10^-15, 1.42109*10^-14, 1.42109*10^-14, 
 1.86517*10^-14, -1.68754*10^-14, -9.76996*10^-15, -8.88178*10^-15, 
 4.61853*10^-14, 4.55621*10^-14, -2.06866*10^-14, -3.57266*10^-15, 
 2.77556*10^-17, 7.34075*10^-12, 9.78551*10^-13, 2.09832*10^-14, 
 8.76188*10^-13, 1.37063*10^-12, 1.39522*10^-12, 4.70224*10^-12, 
 2.50945*10^-14, 6.11733*10^-14} *)
```

Comment: hey man i am sorry i am new to mathematica so i am unable to understand what this all means, could you send me whole syntax, also could you give me some tutorial links so that i can understand this.

Comment: i got it upto the point where you said covars = {cg1,cg2...}. After this i kind of lost it.

Comment: i have edited the equations, there is one more equation which you have not considered it is shown in problem

Comment: If you are new to Mathematica then you should spend at least a minimal amount of effort learning the basics. Mathematica's built-in documentation has a number of tutorials that should help you get started.